# Tulip tree in a container

Tags: trees, containers

I would like a tulip tree but I don't want a tree that will grow over 70 ft tall! Is it possible for it to grow in a container?

Comment: Where do you live, what climate zone?  Are you in  a house or apartment?  More details please..

Comment: Hi kevinskio, I live in a house with a medium-sized yard in Ontario, Canada - Zone 3-4.

Answer (score 4):

Liriodendron tulipifera is indeed a splendid ornamental tree of architectural proportions and as you say, left in open ground would grow to monumental size over time and if left close to a house, would compromise building integrity.

However, you will be pleased to know that this tree and a related species, Liriodendron chinense are well prized as Bonsai specimens and as such are perfect candidates for container growing. As a very basic bonsai fan, I think it would be a wonderful challenge to someone willing to put in the hours and years to bring such a beautiful tree to maturity and their 500 year projected long life would make a life long commitment for entire generations of your family.

You would need to read up more extensively on keeping such a tree in a bonsai state if you were to grow it in a container and some bonsai folk report its leaf size and growth potential make it a difficult candidate for both bonsai and by extrapolation container grown. You would need to do extensive root pruning to ensure the tree would remain manageable in even the short term.

[image: Bonsai Tulip Poplar Tree]

Comment: Oh thank you for your comment, Nikki! It was a $100 tree so I suppose it isn't too much loss if it fails. But yes, I love your idea of a challenge. I will research this further!